# Unable to get correct map using gdirection load method when longitude and latitude are passed

Tags: google-maps-api-2, gdirections

I am using Gdirections google API. In that I am required to pass longitude and latitude in load method as parameters of source and destination. But when I pass longitude and latitude as parameters, it gives me a map with wrong directions. But when I pass source and destination address it gives me correct map.

How can I get a map with correct driving directions when lat and long is passed?

Comment: What language you are using.? What is the code..? Some relevant idea please...

Comment: I am doing the code in javascript

Comment: function setDirections(fromAddress, toAddress, locale) {
   gdir.load("from: " + "#60, Jothi Nivas College Road, 5th Block, Koramangala" + " to: " + "IBC Knowledge Park 4/1 Bannerghatta Road",
            { "locale": locale });
   
 // gdir.loadFromWaypoints(["12.937415,77.618515","12.953371,77.635574"],{"locale":locale});
}

Comment: Above is my method when i paas adress as parameter i am getting correct map directions.But when i paas latitude and longitude i am not getting map with correct directions

Comment: Do one thing... create a GLatLng object to hold a static Latitude and Longitude address... place these objects into an array and then call the loadFromwaypoints function to get the results...

Comment: You do realize that the [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) was officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010, and is only guaranteed to work until May 10, 2013?  New development in that API is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of usage...
try below thing

```
gdir.loadFromWaypoints(["New Y...@40.714490,-74.007130", "NewJer...@40.072410,-74.728565"]);
```

Change New York and NewJer.. With the city or state you want..

Let me know it works for you or not.. Hope it helps..

Comment: I was using the same thing though map was getting displayed but with incorrect directions

Comment: gdir.loadFromWaypoints(["Bangalore@12.937415, 77.618515","Bangalore@12.953371, 77.635574"],{"locale":l‌​ocale});... This should be working...